# Ошибка "Module not found" возникла после того, как webpack стал запускаться из /bin файла собственной библиотекит

Tags: node.js, webpack

Когда я запустил Webpack, я получил следующую ошибку:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './StaticallyImportedModules/JsModuleForStaticImport' in 
'D:\OneDrive\PhpStorm\TestProject\FrontendDevelopment\1_Source\0_Devel
opment\3_FrontendScripts'
```

Как видно из скриншота ниже, файл существует и он прекрасно находился до того, как я внёс новый функционал в своё приложение для сборки проектов, основанное на Webpack:

[image]

Раньше сборка проектов запускалась через gulp с интегрированным webpack-ом, при этом в проекте, использующем данную библиотеку, всё же приходилось создавать gulp-файл, устанавливать связанные с ним зависимости и так далее (моя библиотека лишь давала готовые gulp-таски). Тогда решил упаковать всё это в свою библиотеку, и зарегистрировал новую консольную команду для сборки проекта; теперь проектах, использующих мою систему сборки, писать gulp-таски больше не нужно.

**bin/my-lib**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('../index').interpretConsoleCommandAndExecute(process.argv);
```

Далее, команда `interpretConsoleCommandAndExecute` динамически создаёт конфигурацию webpack и запускает сборку проекта. Разумеется `npm link` я выполнил, но библиотка пока находится локально на моём компьютере, и естественно, не в папкe `node_modules` проекта, в котором она используется.
Обычно к файлами в папки `bin` добавляются расширение имени файла (`.js`), но я, следуя [этому уроку](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js), оставил файл без расширения.

Как та информация, которую мне удалось собрать, так и анализ этой ошибки указывают на то, что с большой вероятность причина кроется именно в файле, находящимся в папке `bin` и символической ссылке, которая была зарегистрирована. Непонятно только то, почему webpack не работает как надо (остальные компоненты библиотеки, например препроцессинг стилей с помощью gulp, работают исправно). Согласно выводу в консоль, webpack ищет файл там, где надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом случае, я всего лишь забыл

```js
//...
resolve: {
  extensions: [
    '.ts', '.js'
  ]
}
//...
```

в Webpack-конфиге.